# Asp.Net MVC 3 App HandleError not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Okay, I think I've ready every post on StackOverflow regarding this and still no luck.

I've confirmed in my global.asax that the HandleErrorAttribute filter is being registered.
I've set `customErrors mode="On"` in my web.config.
I've changed `Layout=null` to `Layout="~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"` in my Error.cshtml file.

I then added a `throw Exception()` in my Account controller's Index action and browse to `localhost:5050/Account/Index` but I wind up with the standard YSOD error stack stuff.

I've even tried the following (although from my understanding it shouldn't matter):

1. Add `[HandleError]` and `[HandleError(View="Error")]` to my controller.
2. Add `defaultRedirect="Error"` to my customErrors in web.config

What else can I do?  Is there a way to tell what's going on in the HandleError filter or to tell if the Error View is being generated at all?

Thanks for your help.

P.S. Incidentally, I'm using VS2010, IE9 & Chrome

Comment: Is there an error in your _layout.cshtml?  That will make it error twice and then it just defaults to the .Net yellow screen.

Comment: Not that I can tell.  This is the same _Layout file that is used by _ViewStart and if I remove the throw from my Action, the view is displayed properly ... no error thrown.

Comment: whats the path listed in your customErrors element for the error file? pleas post your customErrors section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, ignorance is *not* always bliss ... sometimes being ignorant is just plain frustrating!

It turns out I was editing the web.config located in my Views folder instead of the web.config for my site like I thought I was.

Once I added `customErrors mode="On"` to my *real* web.config, things worked great.

Thanks to everyone that tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the problem. It is very likely that there's an error either in your `_Layout.cshtml` or `Error.cshtml` templates. Or in some partial that those templates might be depending upon.

Steps:

1. Create a new ASP.NET MVC 3 application using the default template
2. Add `<customErrors mode="On" />` to web.config
3. Add `throw new Exception();` in the body of the `LogOn` action on the `Account` controller.
4. Run the site and navigate to `/account/logon`
5. The `Error.cshtml` view is correctly rendered

The YSOD you got normally contains an exception stacktrace that should help you isolate the problem. So to try to isolate the problem, try eliminating any potential code in those templates that might cause the problem. Try putting `Layout = null` in the Error template to eliminate the layout. And if there's an error (as I suspect) in either your Layout or Error templates you will end up with this:

[image]

If you still are unable to isolate the problem try subscribing to the `Application_Error` event in your `Global.asax` and see if you can get more information about the exception.